# Bracket notation property accessor for arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript (and Javascript for that matter), you can access an object's properties using the dot notation or the bracket notation:

```
object.property
object['property']
```

Using a concrete example for the latter:

```
const user = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
}
const prop = 'firstName';
console.log(user[prop]);  //"John"
```

My question is if/how bracket notation can be used for array properties where the value in the bracket is a path to an array.  Here is an example:

```
const user = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    nicknames: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Johnny'}, 
        { id: 2, value: 'JD'}, 
        { id: 3, value: 'Dude'}
    ]
}
const prop = 'nicknames[2].value';
console.log(user[prop]);
```

My goal with the `console.log()` would be to print `JD`, but this example would fail because there is, of course, no property of `user` called `nicknames[2].value`;

How can I use bracket notation in this manner with array properties?

Comment: Have a look at lodash's get function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get

Comment: You could use `eval` eg: `console.log(eval("user." + prop));` or create a function that parses the string to extract the property names and indexes.

Comment: If you are expecting JD then you are also suggesting that nicknames[2] is actually the element where the object's id = 2. nicknames[2] actually points to { id: 3, value: 'Dude'}.

Comment: @JanS `get()` FTW!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @JanS's suggestion, I was able to accomplish what I needed with the following use of lodash's `get()` method:

```
const prop = 'nicknames[2].value';
console.log(_.get(user, prop));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not fancy including lodash for a single function then you might consider adding a function onto your object which provides this functionality.

I have provided a snippet with an example which is able to use the type of `prop` string that you specified in your question

```js
const user = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    nicknames: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Johnny'}, 
        { id: 2, value: 'JD'}, 
        { id: 3, value: 'Dude'}
    ],
    byProp (path) {
      return path.split(/\].|\]\[|\[|\./) // split on [] or .
                 .map( el => el.replace(/\]$/,'')) // remove any trailing ']'
                 // loop over split-string to get element
                 // return undefined if the property does not exist
                 .reduce( (obj, el) => obj? obj[el]:undefined, this);
    }
}

console.log(user.byProp('nicknames[2].value'));
console.log(user.byProp('nicknames[1][value]'));
console.log(user.byProp('firstName'));
console.log(user.byProp('firstName.undefined'));
```